Non-uniform sampling of function domain to produce perceptually uniform triangulation of surface
I have a function whose domain is a barycentric coordinate system (visualized as an equilateral triangle) and that outputs a single scalar value, and I would like to sample the domain in order to produce a perceptually-uniform triangulation of the surface (i.e. accounting for changes in gradient).
Below is an example of my problem, using the matplotlib built-in Delaunay triangulation, sampled uniformly w.r.t. the domain (which is not what I want):

(The points/residuals can be ignored; those are experimental data points against which the model surface is being compared.)
As you can see, the surface looks pretty good except near the back corner where the steep gradient leads to some highly-elongated triangles and insufficient sampling to accurately depict the shape. The camera-directed ordering of points/surfaces is a little broken in matplotlib's 3D tools, but the ends of the residual lines opposite the data points should lie ON the function value at those particular inputs, however they currently miss the drawn surface by quite a lot due to insufficient sampling. I am not currently including those points in the triangulation because that causes it to look less uniform, but those function values are known.
So basically, I am looking for a way to sample the domain (two linearly-independent variables) such that I get a perceptually uniform triangulation of the surface, regardless of the gradient.
I've done some searching in this area already, but I am a little overwhelmed with the number of techniques and approaches I've found, and none seem exactly suited for this task (though I am admittedly unfamiliar with the area). Some complications of this system:

The function is technically analytical, but one of the variables used in the equation does not have a closed form, so I fear many techniques like marching cubes, etc. that rely on a dense sampling of the surface do not apply here.
The function is rather expensive to evaluate, so minimal calls are preferred.
The only ground truth information I have is the independent variable values at the sampled points. Any additional information is either calculated directly from those points (e.g. the function value/surface height) or approximated (e.g. gradients, normals, etc.). So basically I cannot "sample the surface" directly.
I would like the points to be perceptually uniform w.r.t. the surface area (something like these examples), so I fear probabilistic approaches may produce unevenly spaced points/unevenly sized triangles.

My current idea is some sort of two-step process: First, perform a sparse uniform sampling of the domain (as I currently am doing, but with fewer points), approximate the gradient at each point/triangle, then resample the points more densely and with a distribution somehow related to the gradient. The potential pitfalls of this approach I foresee are high computation cost and undersampling the flatter/low-gradient regions. I've also thought about a probabilistic approach, sampling a point in each triangle of the first pass with a probability related to the gradient, but I want my sampled points to be perceptually uniform, so I don't know if that idea would be a good fit.
Any advice on this problem is appreciated!
Edit: A few additional notes:

The function values at the corners are known a priori.
The function is less expensive to evaluate at the edges of the domain, but still not trivial.

I also recently found the Marching Triangles algorithm which seems appropriate for this problem, but I fear it will be very expensive to compute for this function, so my question stands.

How exactly is the surface you want to approximate given? You speak of a function frequently, but how are the surface and the function related? Is it via an implicit equation (like $x^2 + y^2 =1$ for a circle) or do you have a parametrisation of the surface?
